# Web2Py.exe Will Not Open

Tags: python, web2py

I am just getting started on a web2py tutorial. I have downloaded the web2py Windows binaries, extracted the files and am simply trying to start by opening web2py.exe

When i double click the icon a black command prompt looking window opens up but then closes immediately, and the web2py Web Framework window does not open as it is supposed to.

Not sure if this is important but I have Python 3.7 installed, do not have any 2.x version installed, but web2py.com does not mention that any of this is needed, it should load up right out of the box. I have searched extensively and do not see anyone else with the same issue. I have tried restarting my computer, deleting and re-downloading the web2py zip folder, but nothing changes.

Edit: Tried opening application from command prompt, same result.
Also I have now tried it on two different Windows machines (one work, one personal) and had the same issue.

Comment: Open a command line and start the program from there. You might be able to see some error messages then.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to run the program from the command prompt per your suggestion but the exact same thing happened as when I double clicked the icon. No error message was returned.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help any further. I used web2py ages ago, didn't like it and haven't touched it since.

Answer (score 0):

open notepad or a text editor and add

```
web2py.exe
pause
```

Save the file with extension .bat. Double click this bat file. If there are any errors, the console will display. If not, you will see web2py window.

Comment: This is the error message received:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "__main__.py", line 128, in <module>
  File "__main__web2py__.py", line 33, in <module>
TypeError: start() takes no arguments (1 given)

I am not really sure what to do with that as I am providing no arguments to 'start()'

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the legacy source code from

http://www.web2py.com/init/default/download

and ran this command in my Mac terminal

```
$ python web2py.py
```

The legacy binaries code for Mac or Windows leads to a 404 which is disconcerting. I also see that the website is running on an insecure connection. Is web2py being maintained regularly?

Answer (score 0):

As per this posting https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/UdF_UNZB1mQ, the current version of binaries are not working and an alternate is suggested there. In general, web2py Google group is very active and you will get better responses there.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use source code version. It's more flexible to use across any platforms.